# I want to add "100" in the list so used append method

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

Want to apply an append method in for loop to add new value to list but the result infinite none. I am new to programming. Below is my code.

```
a = [2, 3, "name",10]

for i in a:
    app = a.append(100)
    print(app)
```

Comment: If you will try to do `print(a)` you will find that you actually got what you wanted. Just didn't look in the right place...

Answer (score 0):

`list.append()` is a mutating method that returns `None`. In other words it changes the list, but doesn't return the list.  Doing `app = a.append(100)` makes `app` refer to the result of `None`.

Change

```
app = a.append(100)
```

to

```
a.append(100)
app = a # these now reference the same mutated list
```

If you don't need two names for the same list drop the `app = a`.

If, on the other hand, you want `a` to reference the original list and `app` to reference a modified list then you would do

```
 app = a + [100]
```

Answer (score 0):

`append` actually works by modifying the original list, rather than returning the list with the item appended. In fact, the function always returns `None`, as you have found. If you instead print the contents of the original list, i.e. `print(a)` rather than `print(app)`, you'll see the items being added.